Spawn Service failed
[ERROR] [1733134962.319213, 10.280000]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[urdf_spawner-8] process has died [pid 15903, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -urdf -model jackal -param robot_description -x 0 -y 0 -z 1.0 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0 __name:=urdf_spawner __log:=/home/kkj/.ros/log/55c9eeae-b097-11ef-b0a5-f756e3648dfc/urdf_spawner-8.log].
log file: /home/kkj/.ros/log/55c9eeae-b097-11ef-b0a5-f756e3648dfc/urdf_spawner-8*.log
roservice list give me
/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model
/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model

log file data for more details                                                                                                             [INFO] [1733134951.381996, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description
[INFO] [1733134951.388301, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1733134952.293956, 0.260000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1733134962.317761, 10.280000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Entity pushed to spawn queue, but spawn service timed out waiting for entity to appear in simulation under the name jackal

please delete the comment  ... all information belongs in the question, please add it there

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
